# Identify movie or TV-series about a portal to a parallel medieval world

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe, medieval

Apologies for the very vague points.

**Looking for the movie or tv-series.**

- The movie or series is likely at least 10 years old.
- Possibly NOT in English. I am asking for a friend who watches dubbed movies and series.
- The theme is the ability to travel between our world and a Game of thrones type ***medieval*** parallel world.
- Unless this series has been adapted in another language than English, it is **similar** but **not** *The Chronicles of Amber* (whose possible [adaption for TV](https://variety.com/2023/tv/news/stephen-colbert-chronicles-of-amber-tv-series-adaptation-1235492097/) ) prompted the question to begin with.
- Family - brothers and sisters in a house meets before using “portal” - animosity between siblings(?)
- Driving in motor car near edge of the parallel world, world behind disappears on the way to medieval world (reminds me of The Langoliers)
- My friend mentions Anthony Hopkins but is not sure and my research did not reveal something with him that matched

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with Amber Chronicles. How is it similar?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't actually Amber?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's been a long time, but doesn't Corwin imply how difficult it would be to drive between shadows because the shifting physics?  Like how he had to find an alternative means to get the effect of gunpowder?

Comment: In Amber there is a scene where "brothers and sisters meet in the castle and using the trumps (creating kind of "portal") to return Brand from the imprisonment". Something like this?

Comment: If the protagonists are driving between worlds and the process is gradual, as implied by your last point, how does the portal in your third point work?  Are they different means of achieving the same result, or do they go to different places?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @DavidW on the contrary, I'm pretty sure he and Random do actually drive (most of the way) to Amber the first time, near the beginning of *Nine Princes in Amber*.

Comment: Please write more descriptive titles, "title of movie or series" just won't cut it. If it's not good enough for Google search, it's also not good here either. Fixed it for you.

Comment: I am blanking on author and title, but I recall reading something that matches this description sometime 2000-2010.  I do not recall whether I read it in French or English but I'm pretty sure the author was French.  Maybe that helps a small bit in searching. The head of the family (royalty?) had been kidnapped or betrayed and was lost somewhere in the parallel worlds.  They could somehow gets clues to his whereabouts through a personal artifact he had left behind in the house.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It has not yet been filmatised

Comment: @AndresF. Apologies. We even tried ChatGPT but there was not enough information for that either. Apologies for the poor memory.

Comment: @Ethan Ah, I was only searching for English titles. It can very well be non-English since the person asking me to find it likely watched it dubbed in another language.

Comment: @Ethan It is just like Oberon was sent to the false quest to cure the Pattern and was captured there. And the Jewel was his most powerfull tool (he left it in the castle).

Comment: @mplungjan "likely watched it dubbed" - so was it movie or some TV film?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi They cannot remember if it was a movie or tv-series, but it was either.

Comment: @mplungjan if you can write a question, you can write a good title that summarizes it. This is true of any question. For example, you left out "medieval" and "parallel world" from the title (which I later added), but those were critical pieces of information. Basically, whenever you write a question think "is this a specific enough search term for Google?". If the answer is "no", then your title isn't good enough here either. Is searching on Google "question about movie title" a good way to go about it, in your opinion?

Comment: @AndresF. I recognise the issue that you fixed, Thanks. This, as you can see, my 4th question since 2017. So apologies for the poor title. In these questions, sometimes a glance at a vague question immediately triggers the answer. In this case less so. I believe the question is acceptable now, no?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it's acceptable in my opinion. Not sure about the close votes, I think those are outdated now. Your question should be good.